# Disable appending custom option SKU to product SKU

Tags: php, magento

Let's say we have :

- product with SKU "product-sku"
- custom option with SKU "custom-option"

If we now add this product with this custom option selected in cart, then the SKU of this product will turn into "product-sku-custom-option" on checkout page.

Is there a way in Magento to disable appending the SKU of the custom option to the SKU of the product or at least getting the original SKU of the product after it has been added to cart ?

Comment: You could change the behavior by changing the method getOptionSku() for configurable products. The method is implemented in the class: Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rule of thumb is never touch the core files. You should extend the `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/<yourtype>.php` and simply do this:

```
public function getOptionSku($optionValue, $skuDelimiter)
{
    return '';
}
```